# Javascript Fetch API status returning undefined

Tags: javascript

With the deprecation of XMLHttpRequest, I have been trying to rewrite a javascript function that checks if a url exists by using Fetch. My console log results in the correct value, but my return statement is always undefined. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function urlExists(url) {
    var request = new Request(url);
    fetch(request).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.status);
        return response.status != 404;
    });
}
```

EDIT: I jumped the gun on a bug based on this error message in console `[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.` My bug was actually elsewhere in my code. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: which return statement? I can't find an issue with your code...

Comment: Your code seems to have no issue, Can you please create jsfiddle for clarity?

Comment: "With the deprecation of XMLHttpRequest" — XMLHttpRequest is not deprecated.

Comment: "my return statement is always undefined" — Which return statement? How are you determining that it is `undefined`? (You have two and neither of them should be capable of producing an undefined result)

Comment: re edit: You still haven't shown how you are determining what the response is, but by removing the `return` statement from `urlExists` you guarantee that `urlExists` will now always return `undefined` (instead of the promise it was getting from `fetch` before).

Comment: My bad actually had a different bug elsewhere in my JS. Unfortunately can't delete this post.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you trying to do a sync operation by writing an async code. Both return statements in your code are relevant to their respective scope. You need to have a **callback** to return the response from fetch.

```
function urlExists(url, callback) {
    var request = new Request(url);
    fetch(request).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.status);
        callback(response.status != 404);
    });
}

/* Usage */
urlExists('http://example.com', (isExist) => {
    if(isExist) {
        console.log('URL found');
    }
    console.log('URL not found');
})
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. The function is returning a boolean based on the staus code being 404. Using a promise removes the need for a callback function.

Comment: This isn't good because it circumvents the reason to use promises.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided does not handle error part. Hence, That might be the reason it was not working.

```js
function urlExists(url) {
          var request = new Request(url);
          return fetch(request).then(function(response) {
             return (response.status != 404);
          }, function(error){
            return false;
          });
    }
    
    urlExists("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").then(result=>{ console.log(result); });

urlExists("https://google.com").then(result=>{ console.log(result); });
```

I have tested this and working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Convert it into this

```
 function urlExists(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          var request = new Request(url);
          fetch(request).then(function(response) {
             resolve(response.status != 404);
          });
        });
    }
```

To Use It

```
urlExists("https://www.google.com").then(result=>{
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: You are right so keep your function as it is but you have to call it with then urlExists("https://www.google.com").then(result=>{
  console.log(result);
});

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to be right. I just wanted to know.

Comment: that's my bad It is the same but you just only to call the function with `then`

Comment: The code provided by @Archie is working file without promise. Why do we need Promise here?

Comment: That's the [nested promise antipattern](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/).

Answer (score -1):

Your function returns a promise, so make sure you're using `await` or `.then(...)` in outer code to access the response correctly

Comment: That can't be the issue. They said they were getting `undefined`. If they failed to `await` or `then` they'd get the promise object.